# How to close google chrome popups with selenium on python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, automation

I am trying to automate sending messages on facebook messanger using python. I have this code until now:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

class Bot:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def loginFacebook(self):
   # btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[1]/input")
    #btn.click()
   email_in = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
   email_in.send_keys("xxxxx@mail.com")

   pw_in = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pass"]')
   pw_in.send_keys("xxxxxx")

   login_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u_0_d"]')
   login_btn.click()

def sendMessageFacebook(self):
    sendMessageBtn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mount_0_0"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/span/div')
    sendMessageBtn.click()
```

The problem is the facebook page after the login opens a pop up to "Allow notifications" which I have to click to Allow or to Block. And this pop up doesn't allow the driver to find the element where the send message button is... But if you click several times on the page (like 4 or 5 times on the page the blur disappears and allows to click the button manually.
How can I click several times on a page or close the popup to be able to find the element?

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = Options()
option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("yourpathtochromedriver",chrome_options=option)
```

this will disable all infobars.

Comment: doenst work. it says: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Google Chrome.app' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home. my permissions are : read and write for everyone

Comment: are you using compatible chromedriver  version  for your browser?

Comment: yes because the all the commands work, the find_element_by_xpath works (the functions of the driver work)

Answer (score 0):

The popup on a website is an other frame of the webpage. So you have to switch to an other frame in order to close it. By using :

```
driver.switch_to_active_element()
```

You ll be able to go to the frame popup. If it doesn't work you can try the other functions that exist to change to an other frame. driver.switch_to_bla_bla_bla()

Then, you ll be able to scrape the popup like the webpage and you ll be able to click on the "close" button or something like that !
Hope I helped you :)